# Checking for decimal character code in element

Tags: javascript

I have a sorting feature I am making for my tables and as such I have used the decimal character codes...

```
&#9650;
&#9660;
```

...to create a representation of an up and down arrow. When I click on the arrow it calls a function to do the sorting (and also to switch the orientation of the arrow). To do this I have been trying to use code along these lines...

```
const assn = this.id;
const text = document.getElementById(assn).innerHTML;
if (text === "&#9660;") {
    document.getElementById(assn).innerHTML = "&#9650;";
}
else {
    document.getElementById(assn).innerHTML = "&#9660;";
}
```

However this does not seem to work as the variable text seems to save as the literal arrow itself, and compare to the literal string "&#9660" instead of the arrow that this string will create. I am wondering if this is the cause, and if so, is there any way in which I can actually compare the character codes together?

I have tried using document.getElementById(assn).textContent too but this seems to have the same effect. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You can do this: `if (text === "▼") {`

Comment: `if(text.charCodeAt(0) === 9660) {` is another option

Comment: I see, it does work. So if I want to replicate this with any other symbol I need to copy and paste the symbol over? If I was working on a CLI is there anyway I could achieve this?

Comment: Just saw your response Nick, that does work too and does seem a bit less prone to CLI troubles.

Comment: @James What do you mean by CLI? Notice you can also use `if (text === "\u25bc") {`

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work for me @Bergi but I will research more into the method to see if some of my other code is conflicting with it. By CLI I meant Command Line Interface (sometimes I am coding on CLI versions of Linux).

Comment: Working on a cli shouldn't stop you from entering the ▼ symbol in your code using whatever method.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try just CSS ? Simplest version below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.arrowControl > span {display:none;}
.arrowControl.down > span.down
, .arrowControl.up > span.up {display:inline;}
</style>
<div id="anyContainer">
  <div class="arrowControl">
    <span class="down" onclick="funcForDown();">&#9660;</span>
    <span class="up" onclick="funcForUp();">&#9650;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then in your JS

```
var arrow=document.querySelector('#anyContainer .arrowControl');
if (arrow.classList.contains('up')){
  arrow.classList.remove('up');
  arrow.classList.add('down');
}
else {
  arrow.classList.remove('down');
  arrow.classList.add('up');
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `arrow.classList.toggle('up')`